# Simple repeated multiplication problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let's say I've multiplied a number by a value and then multiplied that result by that same value $n$ number of times.

$$A = 100, B = Ax, C = Bx, D = Cx, E = Dx$$

So here I've done it four times. How would one find the value for $x$ if I want $E$ to be a specific amount?

Sorry, I'm new here and somewhat new to math too. This might be a really bizarre way to ask a dumb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $E=A\cdot x^4$, therefore $x=\sqrt[4]{\frac EA}$ will do. (If $\frac EA$ is negative, $x$ cannot be real; you can then take $x=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt 2}\sqrt[4]{\left|\frac EA\right|}$). With $n$ instad of $4$ multiplications, try $x=\sqrt[n]{\frac EA}$.

Comment: Perfect! Worked great. Thanks so much. :)